# Java interview - Get secret message from Jar

Tags: java, reflection

This is an interview question which i am trying to find out the answer.
A Jar contain a class file, it has two methods. (open(String) & getMessage()).
Only if you pass the password to open(String) method, you can get secret message from getMessage() method.
How to find the password to unlock it?

EX: If the password is "abacus", then 
open("abacus") --> will return box is unlocked

getMessage()--> Return the secret message.

But how to find the password which is hardcoded inside Jar through coding.

Comment: You can check the bytecode directly or use some decompiler tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with reflection API:

```
    ClassFromJar classFromJar = new ClassFromJar();
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("ClassFromJar");
    Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("getMessage", null);
    method.invoke(classFromJar);
```